# Can I use AIR to create Sony LiveView™ plugins?

Tags: android, plugins, air, flash-builder, sony

I'm interested in creating a plugin for use on my LiveView™ but I am not acquainted with Java with regards to developing for the Android platform. However, I have no problems getting by with As3 / AIR.

So my question is, is it possible to create Sony LiveView™ plugins using the AIR sdk? If so, where do I get started? (e.g. what do I need to configure to get my first Hello World plugin out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to develop for LiveView using Air.

If you would like to use Java, more information and SDK is available at http://sonymobile.com/developer.

/Magnus

Comment: But doesn't AIR now have support for native libraries?

Comment: The LiveView SDK unfortunately does not support AIR, i.e. there are no "native libraries" for LiveView.